# Where does recursive formula for finding solutions to $x^2 \equiv -1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p^k)$ come from?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A year ago I asked a question which concerns a [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1959-13-066/S0025-5718-1959-0105784-2/S0025-5718-1959-0105784-2.pdf) by Shanks where he lays out a particular sieve algorithm for factoring numbers of form $n^2 + 1$.

I still know very little about elementary number theory, but am not a total ignoramus as I was a year ago or so.

My question is: how does one derive the equation (5) from his paper? In case the link gets broken, I will summarize it here.
Given some Pythagorean prime $p$ and integer $k > 1$: if $A_k$ is the smallest solution to the equation
$$n^2 + 1 \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ p^k),$$
then
$$A_{k+1} = A_k + C_k p^k,$$
where
$$C_k \equiv h \frac{A_k^2 + 1}{p^k}\ (\textrm{mod}\ p),$$
and
$$h \equiv A_1 \frac{p + 1}{2}\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$$

I will be satisfied if you just refer me to a chapter of a textbook where this is explained.
Ultimately I want to know if similar recurence can be derived for equations of form $n^2 + D \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ p^k)$ for various $D>1$.

Comment: This is Hensel's lemma.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma

Comment: Thank you! This solves all my issues.